# Convergence of Schwartz functions

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, schwartz-space

I am proving or disproving the following statement:
Let $f_n$ be a sequence of Schwartz functions in $\mathbb R^d$, such that $f_n$ converges to 0 uniformly. Is it true that $f_n$ converges to 0 in $L^p(\mathbb R^d)$ for all $1 \leq p\leq \infty$?

My idea:
The case $p=\infty$ is automatically true, and for simplicity we consider the case $p=1$ only.
Let $\epsilon>0$, and by uniform convergence, there is an $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, for all $x\in \mathbb R^d$,
$$
|f_n(x)|<\epsilon
$$
Notice that $f_n$ is Schwartz, and hence integrable. There is an $M_n>0$ such that we have:
$$
\int_{|x|>M_n}|f_n(x)|<\epsilon
$$
But the problem lies in whether $\sup_n M_n<\infty$. If this is true, then we are done.

If on the contrary this is false, please give a counterexample.
Thank you!

Edited: If the above is hard to prove, please try to prove my original question, assuming $f_n$ converges to 0 in the metric of Schwartz space.

Comment: Try to disprove the statement instead of proving it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $a>0$ let $f_n(x)=n^{-a}\,f(x/n)$. Then $f_n$ converges uniformly to $0$ but $\|f_n\|_p=n^{d/p-a}\,\|f\|_p$ does not converge to $0$ if $1\le p\le d/a$.

If $f_n$ converges to $0$ in the metric of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}(1+|x|)^{d+1}\,|f_n(x)|=0.
$$
From this it is easy to see that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|_p=0$ for all $p\ge1$.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is precise and clear.